# How can I make 3 wire sub-panels compliant with current codes?

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel

The sub-panels in my house are all split-phase 3 conductor with neutral and grounds mixed.  Is there any way to make this compliant without running new 4 conductor feeders? (Some of the feeder cables are not accessible without major renovations.)  What are the possible dangers of this setup?

Comment: Are these panels within the same structure, or detached?
Also, it's still single-phase (or split-phase), not two-phase.

Comment: If it is in place, and was compliant when it was put in, it is compliant now.  If it is not broke, don't fix it.

Comment: I'm a micro-electronics guy not an electrical guy ... thanks for correcting me on the split-phase :) I can only assume it was ever compliant.  This house and renovated heavily before code enforcement was in place.  All of these panels are in the same structure.  The house is rather large so some of the panels are over 100ft away (by cable length) from the main panel (if that makes any difference.)

Comment: Are there any issues with just putting a ground wire to these panels from the main and splitting grounds/neutrals for the panels?  How about splitting the groups/neutrals and adding a grounding rod near the new location?

Comment: Running a separate ground wire between the panels and unbonding neutral and ground is a bad idea. If something breaks the ground wire, you are now in a worse position than you were without a ground wire.

Comment: @SomeGuy, obviously the install is not, and was never, complaint.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey You are the go to guy on this stuff, can you please provide the citation for it. I can make an argument given changes in language between the 2005 and 2008 versions. So please help me.

Comment: @SomeGuy, within the same structure it was never complaint to combine the grounding and grounded (neutral) as the same conductor to a sub-panel. You are correct with regard to a detached structure. Prior to the 2008 NEC a "3-wire" feeder to a detached structure was OK.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey - Thank you, sir. You have taught me something today. Which is what I think this site is all about. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR: your subpanels are seriously screwed up.  Fixing it will require running wires, because the last installer was likely an idiot

We start this journey in NEC 215.6:

> **215.6 Feeder Equipment Grounding Conductor.** Where a feeder supplies branch 
>   circuits in which equipment grounding conductors are required, the feeder shall 
>   include or provide an equipment grounding conductor in accordance with the 
>   provisions of 250.134, to which the equipment grounding conductors of the branch 
>   circuits shall be connected. Where the feeder supplies a separate building or
>   structure, the requirements of 250.32(B) shall apply.

Since all your panels are in the same structure, 250.32(B) is irrelevant (and so is the length of the feeders -- the NEC doesn't care about how long a feeder is provided the voltage drop is within limits), so we move on to 250.134:

> **250.134 Equipment Fastened in Place or Connected by Permanent Wiring Methods 
>   (Fixed) - Grounding.** Unless grounded by connection to the grounded circuit 
>   conductor as permitted by 250.32, 250.140, and 250.142, non-current-carrying 
>   metal parts of equipment, raceways, and other enclosures, if grounded, shall 
>   be connected to an equipment grounding conductor by one of the methods 
>   specified in 250.134(A) or (B).
>
> **(A) Equipment Grounding Conductor Types.** By connecting to any of the 
>   equipment grounding conductors permitted by 250.118.
>
> **(B) With Circuit Conductors.** By connecting to an equipment grounding 
>   conductor contained within the same raceway, cable, or otherwise run with the 
>   circuit conductors.
>
> *Exception No. 1: As provided in 250.130(C), the equipment grounding conductor 
>   shall be permitted to be run separately from the circuit conductors.*

Once again, we ignore the reference to 250.32, but now there are several issues at hand.  First, 250.140 is also irrelevant, as it deals solely with electric ranges and dryers, not feeders.  While 250.142(B) looks promising,

> **(B) Load-Side Equipment.** Except as permitted in 250.30(A)(l) and 250.32(B) 
>   Exception, a grounded circuit conductor shall not be used for grounding non-
>   current-carrying metal parts of equipment on the load side of the service 
>   disconnecting means or on the load side of a separately derived system 
>   disconnecting means or the overcurrent devices for a separately derived system 
>   not having a main disconnecting means.
>
> *Exception No.1: The frames of ranges, wall-mounted ovens, counter-mounted 
>   cooking units, and clothes dryers under the conditions permitted for existing 
>   installations by 250.140 shall be permitted to be connected to the grounded
>   circuit conductor.*
>
> *Exception No.2: It shall be permissible to ground meter enclosures by 
>   connection to the grounded circuit conductor on the load side of the service 
>   disconnect where all of the following conditions apply:*
>
> *(1) No service ground-fault protection is installed.*
>
> *(2) All meter enclosures are located immediately adjacent to the service 
>   disconnecting means.*
>
> *(3) The size of the grounded circuit conductor is not smaller than the size 
>   specified in Table 250.122 for equipment grounding conductors.*
>
> *Exception No.3: Direct-current systems shall be permitted to be grounded on 
>   the load side of the disconnecting means or overcurrent device in accordance 
>   with 250.164.*
>
> *Exception No.4: Electrode-type boilers operating at over 1000 volts shall be 
>   grounded as required in 490.72(E)(1) and 490.74.*

none of the exceptions to it apply at all to your situation, and the reference to 250.32(B)'s exception is also, again, irrelevant.  In addition, 250.30(A)(1) is inapplicable as it deals solely with separately derived systems (such as a generator) and not utility mains service.

This leaves us with 250.130(C):

> **(C) Nongrounding Receptacle Replacement or Branch Circuit Extensions.** The 
>   equipment grounding conductor of a grounding-type receptacle or a branch-
>   circuit extension shall be permitted to be connected to any of the following:
>
> (1) Any accessible point on the grounding electrode system as described in 
>   250.50
>
> (2) Any accessible point on the grounding electrode conductor
>
> (3) The equipment grounding terminal bar within the enclosure where the branch 
>   circuit for the receptacle or branch circuit originates
>
> (4) An equipment grounding conductor that is part of another branch circuit 
>   that originates from the enclosure where the branch circuit for the receptacle 
>   or branch circuit originates
>
> (5) For grounded systems, the grounded service conductor within the service 
>   equipment enclosure
>
> (6) For ungrounded systems, the grounding terminal bar within the service 
>   equipment enclosure

Unfortunately for you, point 5 here isn't a blanket authorization to do what was done in your house, just the ability to run a new ground wire back to the neutral busbar in your service panel.  So, you'll have to run ground wires back from the subpanels to a point tied into the grounding network, then separate neutral and ground at all the subpanels.

As to Longneck's concern about broken ground wires -- while running a single ground wire by itself may be Code (it depends on how your AHJ interprets 250.130(C)), there are two vastly better options:

1. Run new RMC from the main panel to the subpanels via whatever route is convenient and use the RMC itself as a grounding conductor as per 250.118 point 2; this RMC can be sized to accommodate a future feeder upgrade as well, if such a thing is ever needed.  However, this approach does have a much higher upfront cost, as running conduit's quite a bit of work.
2. Run a [single bare conductor type MC cable](http://www.homedepot.com/p/AFC-Cable-Systems-100-ft-6-1-Bare-Armored-Ground-Cable-1302-30-AFC/205070877?N=5yc1vZc57mZ1z10myqZ1z10mzp) as per 250.118 point 10(a).  This is easier/faster than running conduit, but means you'll have to tear both it and the old feeders out to run new feeders in the future.  It does address longneck's concerns about a single bare wire being snipped, though -- cutting MC cable is not something one does save for a full-scale demolition!  (The 6/1 I linked is adequate for any subpanel you'll *ever* find in a residential setting, by the way -- Table 250.122 allows for a 6AWG copper grounding conductor for all circuits up to 200A.)

Comment: Well that sounds much better then when I was thinking I was going to have to done... assuming I can find reasonable chases.  Thanks for the info and suggestions.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the way I'm interrupting 250.130(c) is strictly for repairs for non-grounded branch circuits and receptacles.  250.134 exception (1) should not apply to feeders/subpanels.

Comment: @Kris -- you are right that it's pushing things a bit to run a feeder EGC separately from the other circuit conductors, but in a retrofit situation, I suspect it would be possible to make the case to the AHJ that this is the best one can do.  The language in 250.134 itself isn't all that clear (note the "or" between the refs to (A) and (B)...)